# AJax Search and Jet Search "Cannot modify header information"

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

thank you first of all.

I have this following error on my website. I'm using widgets from Crocoblock, woocommerce and Elementor.

My wordpress error_log gives me the following error:
"PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /home4/"myservername"/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jet-search/includes/ajax-handlers.php on line 254

Going to Jet Search in the file in question, this is the code presented on line 254:

```
public function set_cookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_val ) {
            $expire      = time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS;
            $secure      = ( false !== strstr( get_option( 'home' ), 'https:' ) && is_ssl() );

            setcookie(
                $cookie_name,
                $cookie_val,
                $expire,
                COOKIEPATH ? COOKIEPATH : '/',
                COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                $secure,
                true
            );
        }
```

I tried updating the plugin, changing the code from true to false and deactivating the plugin the error disappears.

Comment: See [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)